# Strange jump in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm probably missing something really obvious here, but I've been going over this over and over and I'm decidedly stuck. In the code below, `$8` is incremented only if `$2 != $0`. Now I double and triple checked and the `beq` instruction works (for example if I change lop to end2, it does go there).

However, for some reason, `$8` is incremented regardless, even if the branch is executed.

```
lop:   beq $3, $0, end2
       and $2, $3, $4

       sll $3, $3, 1

       beq $2, $0, lop     

       addi $8, $8, 1

       j lop
```

I've got to admit I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(The `and` after the first `beq` will always be executed, too.)

MIPS has explicit pipeline hazards; by the time the decision to branch (or not) is made, the following instruction has already progressed far enough through the instruction pipeline that it will be executed regardless.  This is known as the "branch delay slot".

In some cases you can arrange code to take advantage of this; if you can't (or don't want to), you can just put a `nop` in the following instruction.

Some assemblers will reorder code (or fill in the `nop`) for you - e.g. `gas`, the GNU assembler, does, unless you tell it not to with a `.set noreorder` directive.  But you still need to be aware of it when disassembling anyway.

If you're writing code without automatic reordering by the assembler, I recommend annotating the delay slot with some extra indentation to make it stand out:

```
lop:   beq $3, $0, end2
         nop
       and $2, $3, $4

       sll $3, $3, 1

       beq $2, $0, lop     
         nop

       addi $8, $8, 1

       j lop
```

Comment: +1 I hadn't realized the Linux kernel uses a 1-space indent for insns on branch delay slots.

Answer (score 5):

The add instruction is occurring in the [branch delay slot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot) of the `beq`.

Comment: Wow, I don't think I would have actually figured that out, is there any standard way to get around this?

Comment: @user472875: Try putting a `nop` instruction after the `beq`.  Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with MIPS assembler; it's possible that my answer is not correct (in the sense that the assembler may automatically put `nop`s in for you), in which case something else is the problem.

Comment: Some assemblers (e.g. GNU as) can pretend that there is no branch delay slot: add a `.set reorder` directive and let the assembler move the instructions a bit or add a `nop` where necessary.

Comment: No, I unchecked 'delayed branches' in the simulator settings and it stopped happening. I guess a nop would fix it as well. This seems very strange to me, almost like a bug, why are branch delays used to begin with? -> Never mind, just read the Wiki article more thoroughly

Comment: @user472875: They're a side-effect of a pipelined CPU.  By the time the CPU realises that it has to branch, it has already loaded the next instruction, and so has to execute it.

Comment: @user472875: It's either execute an instruction from the branch delay slot, or don't execute anything at all for 1 cycle, while the CPU is fetching the next instruction.