# how to put a instruction into mips delay slot using gnu as?

Tags: assembly, mips

When writing some assembly code using gnu as, i found that the assembler always put a "nop" into jump instruction's delay slot automatically.

how to put a instruction i wanted into the delay slot?

TIA

Comment: `.set noreorder`, see these previous SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807480/weird-mips-assembler-behavior-with-jump-and-link-instruction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115847/mips-assembly-strange-jump